# As of January 2019, what are the top 10 Dapps on EOS?

Tags: dapp, dapp-development

What are the top DAPPS on EOS as of 2019 JAN? Dapps as in "fully" decentralized and also ones that are "centralized". I believe many of the EOS dapps are centralized and not really "decentralized" as the owner can surely pause the contract somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just rattle off 10 in no particular order.

1. [PixEOS](https://pixeos.io/)
2. [Everipedia](https://everipedia.org/)
3. [High Fidelity](https://highfidelity.com/)
4. [NouGit](https://nougit.io/)
5. [Karma](https://www.karmaapp.io/)
6. [Bloks.io](https://bloks.io/)
7. [Dice](https://betdice.one/)
8. Mythical Games ([Blankos](https://blankos.com/))
9. [Hire Vibes](https://www.hirevibes.io/)
10. [Chintai](https://www.chintai.io/)